# Form input OR drop menu

Tags: forms, input, drop-down-menu

Hi I'm trying to make a form where on the name field you can use EITHER text or drop menu (example the drop menu would contain names already in the database whereas the text input would be for new names)

```
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm" style="margin: 1px;">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="Owner">Owner Name: </label>
        <div class="col-sm-4"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="Owner" name="Owner" <?php $q = $opened['Owner']; if(isset($opened['IDNumber'])) { echo "value=$q"; } else { echo "placeholder='Enter Owner Name'";}; ?> required></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">Or Select</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><select class="form-control" id="Owner" name="Owner" required>
        <option>Select</option>
        <?php

        $sql3="SELECT DISTINCT Owner FROM list Order by Owner asc";
        $results = mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql3) or die();

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {

              echo '<option value="'.$row['Owner'].'">'.htmlspecialchars($row['Owner']).'</option>'; 
          }                         
        ?>
    </select></div>
</div>
```

how would i get it to input the data from one OR the other? not both